# ffmpeg resize maintain aspect - filter not found

Tags: image, ffmpeg, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to create image thumbnails that maintain the aspect of the orginal but crop it if the dimensions are too far out.
found a likely code snippet [here](http://www.bogotobogo.com/FFMpeg/ffmpeg_image_scaling_jpeg.php)

```
ffmpeg -i Einstein_500_459.jpg -vf scale="'if(gt(a,320/240),320,-1)':'if(gt(a,320/240),-1,240)'" Einstein_320x240_fit.png
```

but cannot get ffmpeg to execute it. as is it generates error in terminal:

```
ffmpeg -i Einstein_500_459.jpg -vf scale="'if(gt(a,320/240),320,-1)':'if(gt(a,320/240),-1,240)'" Einstein_320x240_fit.png
ffmpeg version 0.10.12-7:0.10.12-1~precise1 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr 26 2014 09:49:36 with gcc 4.6.3
  configuration: --arch=amd64 --disable-stripping --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='7:0.10.12-1~precise1' --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil      51. 35.100 / 51. 35.100
  libavcodec     53. 61.100 / 53. 61.100
  libavformat    53. 32.100 / 53. 32.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 61.100 /  2. 61.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0.  6.100 /  0.  6.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Input #0, image2, from 'Einstein_500_459.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p, 500x459 [SAR 300:300 DAR 500:459], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Incompatible pixel format 'yuvj444p' for codec 'png', auto-selecting format 'rgb24'
[buffer @ 0x236d720] w:500 h:459 pixfmt:yuvj444p tb:1/1000000 sar:300/300 sws_param:
[scale @ 0x235d5e0] [Eval @ 0x7fffcb68f270] Missing ')' or too many args in 'if(gt(a,320/240),320,-1)'
[scale @ 0x235d5e0] [Eval @ 0x7fffcb68f270] Missing ')' or too many args in 'if(gt(a,320/240),-1,240)'
Error when evaluating the expression 'if(gt(a,320/240),-1,240)'.
Maybe the expression for out_w:'if(gt(a,320/240),320,-1)' or for out_h:'if(gt(a,320/240),-1,240)' is self-referencing.
Error opening filters!
```

after escaping single quotes

```
ffmpeg -i Einstein_500_459.jpg -vf scale="\'if(gt(a,320/240),320,-1)\':\'if(gt(a,320/240),-1,240)\'" Einstein_320x240_fit.png
```

it generates error

```
ffmpeg -i Einstein_500_459.jpg -vf scale="\'if(gt(a,320/240),320,-1)\':\'if(gt(a,320/240),-1,240)\'" Einstein_320x240_fit.png
ffmpeg version 0.10.12-7:0.10.12-1~precise1 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr 26 2014 09:49:36 with gcc 4.6.3
  configuration: --arch=amd64 --disable-stripping --enable-pthreads --enable-runtime-cpudetect --extra-version='7:0.10.12-1~precise1' --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-bzlib --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-librtmp --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libcdio --enable-x11grab --enable-libx264 --shlibdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil      51. 35.100 / 51. 35.100
  libavcodec     53. 61.100 / 53. 61.100
  libavformat    53. 32.100 / 53. 32.100
  libavdevice    53.  4.100 / 53.  4.100
  libavfilter     2. 61.100 /  2. 61.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0.  6.100 /  0.  6.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Input #0, image2, from 'Einstein_500_459.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p, 500x459 [SAR 300:300 DAR 500:459], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Incompatible pixel format 'yuvj444p' for codec 'png', auto-selecting format 'rgb24'
[buffer @ 0x1897720] w:500 h:459 pixfmt:yuvj444p tb:1/1000000 sar:300/300 sws_param:
No such filter: '320/240)'
Error opening filters!
```

is this just a syntax problem? or is my ffmpeg missing something? or what?
this is ubuntu 12.04 with what i believe is a full install of ffmpeg, not the libav default thing. any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to show the complete console output from each command and not just an excerpt.

Comment: ok thanks. added full output for verbatim and escaped command.

Comment: Please edit your post and properly format the console output to make it easier to read. Highlight it and press the code button (looks like `{}`), or highlight it and press ctrl+k.

Comment: oops sorry, done. i've gone ahead and tried other escaping schemes , escaping only commas, and escaping single quotes, commas and () and they all throw the "Missing ')' or too many args in 'if(gt(a,320/240),320,-1)'" error.

Comment: 0.10.12 is ancient and unsupported. Please test a recent build from current git master. [Static builds](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) are available and are easy: just download, extract, and run.

Comment: works on latest release without problem. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to install the latest ffmpeg, for anyone else having this issue.

```
ffmpeg -i Einstein_500_459.jpg -vf scale="'if(gt(a,320/240),320,-1)':'if(gt(a,320/240),-1,240)'" Einstein_320x240_fit.png
```

this code worked without issue on ubuntu 12.04 - ffmpeg release: 2.8.3

there is a script to compile the latest ffmpeg on ubuntu 12.04 or 14.04 [HERE](https://gist.github.com/xdamman/e4f713c8cd1a389a5917)

Comment: That link is an old, outdated ripoff of [FFmpeg Wiki: Ubuntu Compile Guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

Comment: it is simple and ready to run, and worked perfectly with a single ./command on 12.04. cheer up.

Comment: It installs stuff you don't need, omits some important encoders, and pollutes the system with packages that conflict with the repo, but you are of course free to follow outdated, unmaintained, random guides.